# Angular: Setting default value in a dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have set up a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B44Ht6pN0XI4e2rMuFdK?p=preview) with basically below code. 
I am unable to see the default value [Bank Account Number] getting selected in the drop down. I see that model is getting updated. But for some reasons, my default value do not get chosen. Can someone help me?

```
//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="services.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="homeCtrl">
  <h1>Other Criteria: {{ otherCriteria.optionText }}</h1>
  <div>
    <select data-ng-model="otherCriteria"
      data-ng-options="o as o.optionText for o in criteria">
    </select>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

//services.js
app.factory("homeService", [
  "$q",
  function($q) {
    function _getDropdownValues() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      var dropdownValues = [{"optionValue":"Bank_Account_Number","optionText":"Bank Account Number","selected":false},{"optionValue":"Bank_Security_Number","optionText":"Bank Security Number","selected":false},{"optionValue":"Cusip","optionText":"Cusip","selected":false},{"optionValue":"Transaction_Description","optionText":"Description","selected":false}];
      deferred.resolve(dropdownValues);
      return deferred.promise;
    }

    return {
      getDropdownValues: _getDropdownValues
    }
  }
]);

//script.js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, homeService) {

  $scope.otherCriteria = {
    optionValue: "Bank_Account_Number",
    optionText: "Bank Account Number",
    selected: false
  };

  homeService.getDropdownValues()
    .then(function(dropdownValues) {
      $scope.criteria = dropdownValues;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E4S1muX4mZavxPadWlle?p=preview).

It's always a better idea to reference a default value via the index of the collection (however you want to reference it)

```
 $scope.criteria = dropdownValues;
 $scope.otherCriteria = $scope.criteria[0];
```

You can find more information [here](http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/)

Basically: Angular.JS uses native JavaScript comparison for comparing the objects. In JavaScript, unrelated to Angular.JS or anything, comparing objects (object literals) is “by reference”, so it doesn’t factor the similarity of the objects. Only checks if the two references compared point to the same object in memory or not

Comment: you should also explain why it's better

Comment: @Lucas, could you please explain why it should be done this way. If I go with  your approach, I will have to assign $scope.otherCriteria only after loading $scope.criteria. Unlike in my plunker, I need to assign  $scope.otherCriteria first, fill some other sections in the page and then load the $scope.criteria.

Comment: You can find more information here: http://gurustop.net/blog/2014/01/28/common-problems-and-solutions-when-using-select-elements-with-angular-js-ng-options-initial-selection/

Basically:
Angular.JS uses native JavaScript comparison for comparing the objects. In JavaScript, unrelated to Angular.JS or anything, comparing objects (object literals) is “by reference”, so it doesn’t factor the similarity of the objects. Only checks if the two references compared point to the same object in memory or not.

Comment: That was helpful. Could you edit and add this information also to your answer to accept it?